# Trying to extract a specific portion of a string using substrings

Tags: java, substring

I'm writing this method that looks at any variation of this kind of string: 
"Movie:Forrest Gump Genre:Drama, Romance    Rating:8.8  Cost:12.50  Year:1994   Top Actors:Tom Hanks    Box Office:55,000,000"

The strings can vary from name, genre, etc. so I'm trying to write a method that would simply retrieve the Cost (in this example it would retrieve 12.50 for me).

Here is my snippet of code

```
public static String getPrice(String movieInfo)//returns the current price in the movie info
{
    String price=movieInfo.substring(movieInfo.indexOf(" Cost: "), movieInfo.indexOf(" Year: "));
    return price;
}
```

I'm not sure if i'm even applying the substring method correctly or if it even suitable within this context, so please let me know if i am wrong for using that substring method in this context.

Comment: you'll need to add a delimiter (* for instance) to seperate the different parts, and use String s split method.
then, iterate over the array of results, .startsWith("Cost:")
should help

Comment: what are you currently getting in price?

Comment: What happen if you test this code in your IDE? What happen if you do some debug to that code?

Comment: The program receives an error branching from this method

Comment: Only a suggestion: You could use `String.matches` and use Regex for a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is interesting. Strings are really groovy in the sense that they can have many different methods asking for the same thing but called different ways. The way I would tackle this problem is by simply making everything **one giant string (no spaces)**.

**How is this done?** You need to be able to know that a certain character is never going to show up in a string like this. For example, your colon (:) character can work fine. However, to turn a spaced string into a non-spaced string is the most complex part. We want to replace each space with a colon, and remove every current colon.

```
String ufInfo = "Movie:Forrest Gump Genre:Drama, Romance Rating:8.8 Cost:12.50 Year:1994 Top Actors:Tom Hanks Box Office:55,000,000"
public String makeCodeFriendlyString(String infoString) {
  return infoString.replaceAll(":", "").replaceAll(" ", ":"); // Why remove colons and then add spaces?
}
```

What this code does is create our ufInfo (userFriendlyInfo) String and store the data into it. The method called `makeCodeFriendlyString(String infoStirng)` does exactly what it's called. It changes each current colon to a nothing, and each current space to a colon. You'll understand why we removed the colons now:

```
String[] splitInfo = makeCodeFriendlyString(ufInfo).split(":");
public static String getPrice(String cfInfo) {
  for(String s : splitInfo) if(s.startsWith("Cost") return s.substring("Cost".length());
  return "NOT-FOUND";
}
```

What this code now does, is creates an array of all the data stored in the string (eg, movie title, genre, rating, etc.) but all of the data next to it is connected to it. **How do we fix this?** This is not really a problem. We **WANT** this! Since we now have a string like "Cost12.50" we can easily collect the data we need. We know that we are looking for the cost, so we need a substring of the string we are currently working with. `for(String s : splitInfo)` is an enhanced for loop. It iterates through all the data sets the current string being iterated into the value s. `if(s.startsWith("Cost")` checks to see if the current string starts with "Cost". If it is, `return s.substring("Cost".length());` will return the substring of `"Cost12.50"` of whatever is after "Cost" so it would return "12.50"

Report any bugs!

Glad to help anytime,
Jarod.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different methods that you can use, couple of points in your current method to make it work always:

> 1. If every "Cost:" attribute is followed by a "Year:" attribute then it will work
> 2. You need to start from movieInfo.indexOf("Cost:") + "Cost:".length() **(which is 5)**

Assuming there will be a space after the cost and next attribute this should also work for any sequence of attributes:

```
  String cost  = movieInfo.split("Cost:")[1].split(" ")[0];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `"Cost".length()` is equal to 4. You're probably thinking of the final index location which is 5.

Comment: @mastercork889 it is `"Cost:".length()` that is 5

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I did not see the colon. But then again, I am also correct; "Cost".length() does equal 4. ;P

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do this, I would use regexp to get the price.

```
     String movieInfo = "Movie:Forrest Gump Genre:Drama, Romance Rating:8.8 Cost:12.50 Year:1994 Top Actors:Tom Hanks Box Office:55,000,000";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Cost:(\\d+\\.\\d+) ");
   Matcher matcher = p.matcher(movieInfo);
   matcher.find();
   System.out.println(">>"+matcher.group(1)+"<<");
```

Here an example.